# How to get the number of p tag in each file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading the html files to the div like this

```
var j1 = $('<div class = "cl1">').load('components/1.html');
                var j2 = $('<div class = "cl2">').load('components/2.html');
                var j3 = $('<div class = "cl3">').load('components/3.html');                


            $("#search_content").append(j1);
            $("#search_content").append(j2);
            $("#search_content").append(j3);
```

I want to get the count of p tag in each file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can search each of the elements containing the documents for the `p` tag. In your given snippet:

```
var j1 = $('<div class = "cl1">').load('components/1.html', function() {//after content loaded
    var ptags = j1.find("p").length
});
```

Update: If you wish to use all three together he should use promises - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507181/using-jquery-load-with-promises) for loading content with promises

Comment: This will work, but how would the OP use all three counts together?

Answer (score 0):

so you need to count for every file? load a file, count number of paragraphs and load another, then count again?
to count i thisn the simplest way is:

```
function count_pars(){
var n=0;
$('p').each(
function(){
n=n+1;
})
//do stuff 
}
```

and use like this:

```
$("#search_content").append(j1);
count_pars();
```