# Jquery .load function response

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to display response of PHP script within a div element `<div id="divname"></div>`

```
jQuery('#divname').load('TEST.php',{
  'id' : id
});
```

My code works as expected and successfully insert «1» inside this div.

TEST.php file:

```
<?php
  echo '1';
?>
```

...but I would also like to alert the response in the same time using jQuery, someting like this:

```
jQuery('#divname').load('TEST.php',{
  'id' : id
}, 
alert(response); //????
);
```

Can You help me?

Comment: Use `$.get` with a callback or `$.ajax`.

Comment: I would also suggest to use `$.get` or `$.ajax`, than you can also check if the action executed, failed, succeeded, and more. See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery load with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507181/using-jquery-load-with-promises)

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, I would use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this action:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "TEST.php"
})
  .done(function( data) {
    // alert( "Returned data: " + data );
    $('#divname').html(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "Loading failed" );
  });
```

You can then check if the action succeeded (done) or failed (fail).

In the done function, data is the data that returns from the request.

Comment: You are missing `$('#divname').html(data);` to match the example code fully.

Comment: Thanks @Adder, changed it

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback function , [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
jQuery('#divname').load('TEST.php',{
       'id' : id
  },  function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) post about how *callbacks* work. The code below should work as you're expecting.

```
jQuery('#divname').load('TEST.php',{
    'id' : id
}, response => alert(response));
```